# Invalid covariant return type in triple nested class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am getting error when running this code :

> prog.cpp:36:25: error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual const EEE::N::D* EEE::N::d() const’
>
> ```
>    virtual const D *d() const { return 0; }
>                      ^
> ```
>
> prog.cpp:24:25: error:   overriding ‘virtual const EE::N::D* EE::N::d() const’
>
> ```
>    virtual const D *d() const{ return 0; }
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class E {
public:
    class N {
    public:
       class D{
       public:
           D() {}
       };
       virtual const D *d() const{ return 0; }
    };
};

class EE : public E {
public:
   class N : public E::N {
   public:
       class D : public E::N::D {
       public:
           D() : E::N::D()  {}
       };
       virtual const D *d() const{ return 0; }   // No error here
   };
};

class EEE : public EE {
public:
   class N : public EE::N {
   public:
       class D : EE::N::D {
       public:
          D() : EE::N::D()  { }
       };
       virtual const D *d() const { return 0; }  // Error here  why?
   };
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you are using private inheritance and there is no available conversion to the base type.

Comment: Aah thanks. Things that happen at midnight!

Comment: @Saurabh Where are you from? It's the afternoon in America where I'm at. :D